# Copy Directory recursively and overwrite all files without user confirmation

Tags: delphi, recursion, winapi, directory, copy

I have a simple function:

```pascal
function CopyDir(const fromDir, toDir: string): Boolean;
var
  fos: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@fos, SizeOf(fos));
  with fos do
  begin
    wFunc  := FO_COPY;
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY;
    pFrom  := PChar(fromDir + #0);
    pTo    := PChar(toDir)
  end;
  Result := (0 = ShFileOperation(fos));
end;
```

When I copy, a confirmation window pops up saying that a file already exists, asking if it should be overwritten.

I would like to avoid this popup and overwrite everything without confirmation.

Comment: On a side note, `fos.pTo` must also be double-null terminated: `pTo := PChar(toDir + #0);`

Comment: You can find the answer by reading the documentation for `SHFileOperation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shfileopstructa) `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION` to eliminate alerts